# ¿Como obtener el id (int) de varios layouts con variables enumeradas en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Buenas, quisiera saber como obtener el id de una serie de layouts que tienen nombres de variables parecidos, en este caso su sufijo es un numero.

Quiero almacenar sus ID en un arreglo. Pero evidentemente no puedo cambiar el numero por una concatenación del numero, porque entonces el dato que voy a asignar se convierte en un String.

No se que métodos me darían la comodidad de hacer esto, aquí dejo en código planteado algo similar a lo que quiero hacer pero obviamente no funciona por lo que ya mencioné.

```
int[] CASILLAS = new int[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9;i++){
    CASILLAS[i] = R.id.imageCas+""+i; 
}
```

Comment: Cuando lo concatenas pasa a ser un String, has probado a pasarlo a entero? Haz CASILLAS[i] = Integer.parseInt(R.id.imageCas+""+i); tendrás que hacer control de excepciones, es necesario cuando parseas un String a int

Comment: Creo que no sirve, solo estaría manejando el valor entero de la cadena correspondiente al hacer ese parseo.

Answer (score 1):

Usar lo que tal vez es obvio, en realidad es incorrecto, ya que al parsear `R.id.imageCas+""+i` dará como resultado un valor incorrecto, incluso un valor que podría no ser entero por la longitud.

```
int valorId = Integer.parseInt(R.id.imageCas+""+i);
```

---

Los ids generados por cada recurso que se encuentra en tu proyecto son de tipo entero y son escritos dentro del archivo `R.java`, como ejemplo para los layouts se tiene:

```
 public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_main=0x7f04001e;
    public static final int activity_alert=0x7f04001f;
    public static final int activity_configuration_alerts=0x7f040020;
    public static final int activity_contact=0x7f040021;
    public static final int activity_detail=0x7f040022;
    public static final int activity_email=0x7f040024;
    public static final int activity_gallery=0x7f040026;
    public static final int activity_main_bubble=0x7f040029;
 }
```

**pero estos id´s pueden cambiar** por esa razón como sugerencia es almacenar el nombre del layout o recurso, dentro de un array de valores enteros, por ejemplo:

```
private static final int[] mylayouts = new int[]{R.id.activity_main, R.id.activity_alert, R.id.activity_configuration_alerts, R.id.activity_contact, R.id.activity_detail, R.id.activity_email, R.id.activity_gallery, R.id.activity_main_bubble};
```

Comment: No me sirve del todo, pero bueno, esto me aclara otro problema que estoy teniendo, gracias.

Comment: Si deseas obtener los id de los recursos que se encuentran en tu proyecto,   la única forma es definirlos directamente en un array.